# Word choice in a sentence and meaning

Tags: word-choice

醬油 を**掛けて**辛口で食べたい俺でも甘めの卵焼きが美味い

What does **掛けて** mean here? Does it mean "attach"? Why can't I use 付けて instead?

What is the difference in using 辛口 and 塩辛い? Both means salty

Comment: Definition 6: https://jisho.org/search/%E6%8E%9B%E3%81%91%E3%81%A6%E3%82%8B

Comment: Not sure what dictionary you use, but WWWJDIC (e.g. via jisho.org) has "(6) to pour (liquid) onto" for 掛ける...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This 掛ける means "to pour". ～**を**醤油**に**つける is "to dip (something) in syoyu", and ～**に**醤油**を**かける is "to put syoyu (on something)". These are two different ways of using say sauce, and neither is more correct than the other.

塩辛い only means "salty" as the kanji suggests, and it often has a negative connotation. 辛口(の) is neutral, and it also means "spicy/hot" or "dry (alcohol)" as well, depending on the food it modifies.